# Informix varchar to text

Tags: informix

I'm new to informix and I was asked to make some necessary changes to some tables.
I'm modifying a table column type. The current column is varchar(255) and I need to modify it to text. I was told to load the current data to a file, make the necessary changes and unload it back to the table. But I always get an error:

```
load from 'bens' insert into 'informix'.bens(      id_diligencia ,      id_tipo_bem ,      numero ,      especie ,      descricao,      valor ,      commum ,      voice_record ,      _ts )
SQL Error (-847): Error loading file C:\Users\Admin\.ags\userdata\ServerStudio\datastage\bens
SQL Error (-79716): System or internal error java.io.IOException
Error Position: Ln: 1 Col: 0
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
unload to 'bens'
select
     id_diligencia ,
     id_tipo_bem ,
     numero ,
     especie ,
     descricao,
     valor ,
     commum ,
     voice_record ,
     _ts
from 'informix'.bens2;

load from 'bens'
insert into 'informix'.bens(
     id_diligencia ,
     id_tipo_bem ,
     numero ,
     especie ,
     descricao,
     valor ,
     commum ,
     voice_record ,
     _ts
)
```

The column being modified is the column "descricao".

What is happening and how can I make it right?

Comment: Why do you think you need to modify your VARCHAR column to TEXT?  What do you know about the BYTE and TEXT blob types?  Do you know that TEXT types are a pain in the posterior?  Are you sure you don't want to use LVARCHAR?  Or CLOB?  Either of those would probably be a better choice than TEXT.  Why are you changing the type and what are the criteria that the new type needs to meet?

Comment: Then, pragmatically, are you sure that the UNLOAD is working?  The LOAD and UNLOAD statements are peculiar — they are not recognized by the server.  They are simulated by the front-end code (DB-Access, ISQL, I4GL, other DB-* utilities).  I'm not certain that they aren't emulated in JDBC, but I'll be a little surprised if they are — I'm sure they're not emulated in ESQL/C and probably not in ODBC either (and I don't expect them to be emulated in JDBC, but I'm open to learning).

Comment: By the paths in the error messages, you are using AGS Server Studio. Like Jonathan said, `LOAD` and `UNLOAD` are not Informix SQL commands, they are implemented by the clients. You should contact AGS for support. That being said, do you have the same error if you create a couple of simple tables, 1 with a `VARCHAR` column, the other with a `TEXT` column and then use the Server Studio `UNLOAD` / `LOAD` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. As for the answers, yes, the load and unload statements are working. I tried removing the TEXT column from the table and replacing it with an LVARCHAR and it worked just fine. And the reason for the load and unload statements in just to migrate the data between tables after the modifications.

Comment: As for the "Why are you changing the type and what are the criteria that the new type needs to meet?", I just ask my manager, as it's the first time I'm working in informix, and he said the reason for the TEXT type was that it doesn't have a space limit. But if it doesn't work very well we can just as well use an NVARCHAR MAX LENGTH (?).

Comment: Ok, so NVARCHAR can only take up to 255 bytes, so I guess LVARCHAR is the chosen one. Well, anyway, thanks for the help. :)